# Мок для вызова конструктора

Tags: java, тестирование, юнит-тесты, junit, mockito

```
Class A{
   public void doPost(req, resp){
       Something something = new Something("email", "password");
   }
}
```

Как замокать в PowerMockito или Mockito строчку

```
Something something = new Something("email", "password");
```

Comment: Не просто же так, что данный сайт - это SO на русском!

Comment: В Мокито нельзя замокать одну строчку, можно только весь метод.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать `Something` зависимостью и передавать ее в конструктор класса `A`. Создавать же зависимость нужно будет извне.

```
сlass A {
   private Something something;

   public A(Something something) {
       this.something = something;
   }

   public void doPost(req, resp){
       // использование something
   }
}
```

Тогда замокать это можно будет очень просто:

```
public void Test() {
    // создать явно или использовать Mockito
    Something someMock = new Something("another_email", "another_password");
    A a = new A(someMock);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerMockito.whenNew(TheClass.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(something);

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]